# Install new root certificate authority (CA) in windows

Tags: windows-7, security, certificate

I am trying to use [ninite](http://ninite.com/) to get my new laptop set up quickly.
However when I try to install, windows complains about the CA. The website ninite.com also shows certificate problems. They use a root CA (COMODO Certification Authority) that is not included into windows 7 by default.

However I am not able to install that CA. I can view the certrification path for the ninite.com cert. I can view the cert for COMODO. However I cannot see any option to install it.

Any clues?

Comment: does it have a secure website?? an `https` one?? If yes then go to that site and get the certificate from der...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I did: I checked the certificate settings under Internet Options -> Content. There I found that Comod was registered as a valid INTERMEDIATE CA. So I exported this cert. and Imported it as a trusted root CA. Now ninite works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Ninite's (root) certificate is accepted on Windows and I am unsure why you are getting this error.

Try checking your date/time and make sure it is set correctly.

If it is, try performing a Windows update and downloading all Root Certificate updates.

Comment: I did several updates of windows now. Still no luck. Could you specifiy what you exactly mean by 'downloading all Root Certificates' Is there a tool for that? Can I do it on the MS-Homepage?